# Magento barcode script to standalone

Tags: php, image, barcode

A while ago a friend wrote this code for me for generation barcodes in magento 1. Which we use in our neworder mails.
But it suprised me it was using mage.php .... but had further nothing to do with fetching data from magento.

Here is the code:

```
<?php
require_once 'app/Mage.php';
umask(0);
Mage::app();
Mage::app()->loadArea(Mage_Core_Model_App_Area::AREA_FRONTEND);
if( isset($_GET['ord']) && strlen($_GET['ord']) > 5 ) {
    header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
    $barcodeOptions = array('text' => $_GET['ord']);
    //$rendererOptions = array();
    $rendererOptions = array('imageType' => 'jpeg');
    // Draw the barcode in a new image,
    $imageResource = Zend_Barcode::draw(
        'code39', 'image', $barcodeOptions, $rendererOptions
    );
    imagejpeg($imageResource);

} else { echo "<pre><b>Error:</b> required input not found\n"; }
?>
```

And i use it in my transactional mails like

```
<img src="//domain.com/barcode.php?ord={{var order.increment_id}}">
```

And that works great. But now we are migrating to magento2.
And i would like to run the script as a standalone script. But commenting out the first 4 lines will not works, than it says that the image contains errors and cannot be shown.

What am i doing wrong or missing here?

Comment: You're not loading the Zend_Barcode class anymore.  You'll have to look for a new php barcode class (which there are a lot) and use that instead of Magento.

Comment: that is new for me .... could you help me a bit?

Answer (score 0):

If you google "php barcode" you'll find a few scripts and stack overflow question/answers.

I've used the package from http://www.barcodebakery.com/ before and it's easy to use, they've got an example on their site.